# How to calculate screenLeft and screenTop in terms of percentage?

Tags: vb.net, web

I can get the X and Y coordinates of the window using `screenLeft` and `screenTop`.
But, I need to convert the pixel values into percentage. What's the formula for doing it?

I did this for width and height conversion in vb.net,

```
Dim widthpix As Integer = CType(sItems(0), Integer)
Dim heighpix As Integer = CType(sItems(1), Integer)
widthinpercent = CInt((widthpix / PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width) * 100)
heightinpercent = CInt((heighpix / PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)*100)
```

What's the formula to convert `window.screenLeft` and `window.screenTop` in percentage?

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
Dim widthinpercent As Integer = CInt((Me.Location.X / Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width) * 100)
Dim heightinpercent As Integer = CInt((Me.Location.Y / Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height) * 100)
MsgBox(" X =" & widthinpercent.ToString() & "% | Y =" & heightinpercent.ToString() & "%")
```